# Override customer listing magento2 - uicomponent

Tags: customer, grid, uicomponent, magento-2.1.7, listing

I need to change target of the customer grid of admin. The default is `startEdit`, but the client didnt like. He wants a link for customer edit in the row.

```
<item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
```

to

```
<item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
```

Only this. How I override this?

I try to create a **`customer_listing.xml`** in `MyName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component` but didn´t work.

Comment: Which Magento version you are using (2.x.x)?

Comment: Im using the 2.1.7

Answer (score 2):

If the main goal is redirect to the edit form - here the code of the `customer_listing.xml` file which should work in your custom module (I have tested it locally and it works fine for me):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <settings>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**PS:** Tested on Magento CE 2.2.1

---

#### Update

Here the version for the **Magento < 2.2.x** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Edit:**

**How to override :**

Since a lot of people in comments were asking how to override..
you need to override the `customer_index_index.xml` in this customer_listing is referenced.

Comment: I did that. If I change this in the vendor folder, works fine. But  when I put this file in my module, dont work.

Can you tell me how do yout structure folders ? In my module I have a etc/di.xml with this: <arguments><argument name="themes" xsi:type="array"><item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Ibp/ThemeTheme</item></argument></arguments>
and my customer_listing.xml in view/adminhtml/ui_component; I forget something?

Comment: @MarianaNassarDutra for the test I added it here: `app/code/MageWorx/ShippingRules/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`

Comment: Dont works for me. I dont know what im doing wrong. :/

Comment: I put your code and show this error: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Element 'settings': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( column, actionsColumn, selectionsColumn ).
Line: 4

Comment: @MarianaNassarDutra Because you are using older version of Magento. There was a lot of changes since the 2.1.7 release. I'll check how to implement this changes on the version 2.1.7 later.

Comment: @MarianaNassarDutra I've added updated code for your Magento version

Comment: Didnt work yet.. Dont have an error, but dont change do click.

Comment: Did you clean a cache?

Comment: cache was disabled.

Comment: @MarianaNassarDutra It's very strange, because for me both updates works fine. Did you copy&paste the solution as-is or did copy only part of it?

Comment: only part I need. Only the part in post.. But I try with all page and didnt work too.  :/

Comment: @MarianaNassarDutra Could you share your module on the github or bitbucket? I will try to reproduce it locally.

Comment: https://github.com/mariananassar/change-click-customer-magento2

Comment: @MarianaNassarDutra You have a missprint in the `adminhtml` directory name, change the `adminthml` to the `adminhtml`

Comment: Sorry, I create wrong only in github. I will change there.

Comment: I have added an edit on how to override, feel free to revert if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here, I just want to show the dates in pt-br format in the **Date of Birth** field. So, I copy **customer_listing.xml** file to **"MyVendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/customer_listing.xml"**, and put dateFormat tag in **dob** field, like this:

```
<column name="dob" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="170">
     <settings>
         <timezone>false</timezone>
         <dateFormat>dd/MM/y</dateFormat>
         <skipTimeZoneConversion>true</skipTimeZoneConversion>
         <filter>dateRange</filter>
         <dataType>date</dataType>
         <label translate="true">Date of Birth</label>
         <visible>false</visible>
     </settings>
 </column>
```

So, any ideia to how make the override works correctly?

PS: **dateFormat** tag works correctly in **created_at** field.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no ideia yet :/

Comment: My solution to this specific problem was creating a new admin theme, and override the intire customer_listing.xml file.